# hibernate.properties not found, bytecode provider name : cglib

Tags: java, hibernate, console

Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA

- Hibernate 3.2.6
- hibernate.properties not found
- Bytecode provider name : cglib
- using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
- configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
- Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
- Property [hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer] has been renamed to [hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer]; update your properties appropriately
- Configured SessionFactory: null

Comment: Please put correct question details to describe what you are trying to achieve and in your question provide stack trace of error. In short be more descriptive so that one can help you immediately.

Comment: Sorry. i found what it is? Its just a log... while running the program its printing in the console....Thanks to @ShaikhMohammedShariq